# Is there a way to know by which Python version the .pyc file was compiled?

Tags: python, compilation

Is there any way to know by which Python version the `.pyc` file was compiled?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can get the magic number of your Python as follows:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.2
# python
>>> import imp
>>> imp.get_magic().encode('hex')
'd1f20d0a'
```

To get the magic number for a pyc file you can do the following:

```
>>> f = open('test25.pyc')
>>> magic = f.read(4)
>>> magic.encode('hex')
'b3f20d0a'
>>> f = open('test26.pyc')
>>> magic = f.read(4)
>>> magic.encode('hex')
'd1f20d0a'
```

By comparing the magic numbers you'll know the python version that generated the pyc file.

Comment: to compare the magic word written as an integer in [Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3460198f6ba40a839f105c381f07179aba1e8c61/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L131) with `imp.get_magic()` bytes (Python 3): `int.from_bytes(imp.get_magic()[:2], 'little')` (ignore `b'\r\n'`) e.g., `imp.get_magic() == b'3\r\r\n'` corresponds to `3379` (Python 3.6).

Answer (score 61):

The first two bytes of the `.pyc` file are the magic number that tells the version of the bytecodes. The word is stored in little-endian format, and the known values are:

| Python version | Decimal | Hexadecimal | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Python 1.5 | 20121 | 0x994e |  |
| Python 1.5.1 | 20121 | 0x994e |  |
| Python 1.5.2 | 20121 | 0x994e |  |
| Python 1.6 | 50428 | 0x4cc4 |  |
| Python 2.0 | 50823 | 0x87c6 |  |
| Python 2.0.1 | 50823 | 0x87c6 |  |
| Python 2.1 | 60202 | 0x2aeb |  |
| Python 2.1.1 | 60202 | 0x2aeb |  |
| Python 2.1.2 | 60202 | 0x2aeb |  |
| Python 2.2 | 60717 | 0x2ded |  |
| Python 2.3a0 | 62011 | 0x3bf2 |  |
| Python 2.3a0 | 62021 | 0x45f2 |  |
| Python 2.3a0 | 62011 | 0x3bf2 | ! |
| Python 2.4a0 | 62041 | 0x59f2 |  |
| Python 2.4a3 | 62051 | 0x63f2 |  |
| Python 2.4b1 | 62061 | 0x6df2 |  |
| Python 2.5a0 | 62071 | 0x77f2 |  |
| Python 2.5a0 | 62081 | 0x81f2 | ast-branch |
| Python 2.5a0 | 62091 | 0x8bf2 | `with` |
| Python 2.5a0 | 62092 | 0x8cf2 | changed `WITH_CLEANUP` opcode |
| Python 2.5b3 | 62101 | 0x95f2 | fix wrong code: `for x, in ...` |
| Python 2.5b3 | 62111 | 0x9ff2 | fix wrong code: `x += yield` |
| Python 2.5c1 | 62121 | 0xa9f2 | fix wrong lnotab with for loops and storing constants that should have been removed |
| Python 2.5c2 | 62131 | 0xb3f2 | fix wrong code: `for x, in ...` in listcomp/genexp |
| Python 2.6a0 | 62151 | 0xc7f2 | peephole optimizations and `STORE_MAP` opcode |
| Python 2.6a1 | 62161 | 0xd1f2 | `WITH_CLEANUP` optimization |
| Python 2.7a0 | 62171 | 0xdbf2 | optimize list comprehensions/change `LIST_APPEND` |
| Python 2.7a0 | 62181 | 0xe5f2 | optimize conditional branches: introduce `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` and `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` |
| Python 2.7a0 | 62191 | 0xeff2 | introduce `SETUP_WITH` |
| Python 2.7a0 | 62201 | 0xf9f2 | introduce `BUILD_SET` |
| Python 2.7a0 | 62211 | 0x03f3 | introduce `MAP_ADD` and `SET_ADD` |
| Python 3000 | 3000 | 0xb80b |  |
|  | 3010 | 0xc20b | removed `UNARY_CONVERT` |
|  | 3020 | 0xcc0b | added `BUILD_SET` |
|  | 3030 | 0xd60b | added keyword-only parameters |
|  | 3040 | 0xe00b | added signature annotations |
|  | 3050 | 0xea0b | `print` becomes a function |
|  | 3060 | 0xf40b | PEP 3115 metaclass syntax |
|  | 3061 | 0xf50b | string literals become unicode |
|  | 3071 | 0xff0b | PEP 3109 raise changes |
|  | 3081 | 0x090c | PEP 3137 make `__file__` and `__name__` unicode |
|  | 3091 | 0x130c | kill str8 interning |
|  | 3101 | 0x1d0c | merge from 2.6a0, see 62151 |
|  | 3103 | 0x1f0c | `__file__` points to source file |
| Python 3.0a4 | 3111 | 0x270c | `WITH_CLEANUP` optimization |
| Python 3.0a5 | 3131 | 0x3b0c | lexical exception stacking, including `POP_EXCEPT` |
| Python 3.1a0 | 3141 | 0x450c | optimize list, set and dict comprehensions: change `LIST_APPEND` and `SET_ADD`, add `MAP_ADD` |
| Python 3.1a0 | 3151 | 0x4f0c | optimize conditional branches: introduce `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` and `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` |
| Python 3.2a0 | 3160 | 0x580c | add `SETUP_WITH`, tag: cpython-32 |
| Python 3.2a1 | 3170 | 0x620c | add `DUP_TOP_TWO`, remove `DUP_TOPX` and `ROT_FOUR`, tag: cpython-32 |
| Python 3.2a2 | 3180 | 0x6c0c | add `DELETE_DEREF` |

Sources:

- Python/import.c - merged by aix from Python 2.7.2 and Python 3.2.2
- Little endian hex values for comparison first two bytes of Igor Popov's method added by jimbob

Comment: `@aix` also a nice answer, but usually a programmatic solution is easy to understand as `@Popov` gave. Thanks indeed.

Comment: @AamirAdnan: But what if you don't happen to have the python version that created the .pyc file?

Comment: No problem.  Your answer was great and now its a simple table lookup using `with open('test51.pyc') as f: magic=f.read(2); magic.encode('hex')`.

Comment: `@Jefromi` Oh yeah what a point man, in that case `@Popov` solution `Fails` then. As it will never matched with the `python version hex code` to the `hex code of first two bytes` of `.pyc` file. And i will never know what was the version. And eventually i have to go to `@aix` solution for Python Version lookup. Am i right?:)

Comment: @AamirAdnan: Right, the other solution tackles a slightly different problem, namely: "is this `.pyc` file compatible with the Python version that I am running?" Whether this what you want, I don't know.

Comment: updated magic number list @ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/pytype/master/pytype/pyc/magic.py

Answer (score 17):

Or, if you have a GNU/Linux system you can use the command "file" in a terminal:

```
$ file code.pyc
> code.pyc: python 3.5.2 byte-compiled
```

Comment: This is so much easier

Comment: Thanks. But I got `test2.cpython-38.pyc: data` under Windows WSL Ubuntu with python 3.8.5 I don't know why.

Comment: @Rick it depends on the release of the "file" program itself, my file command is from BSD general commands and my version is 5.39.
The source code can be found here: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/contrib/file
and the file where the rules for .pyc files are written is here: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/contrib/file/magic/Magdir/python

Comment: `file` is not necessary if it's captured in the filename itself. Now `ls` is sufficient: `ls src/__pycache__/code.cpython-310.pyc`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my [script](https://gist.github.com/delimitry/bad5496b52161449f6de) in Python that detects and returns the version of Python by which the file (*.pyc or *.pyo) was compiled.

It detects versions of Python from Python 1.5 up to last Python 3 build.

Comment: I couldn't find my magic number in the using the other answers, thanks for the script!

Answer (score 3):

The official Python github repository no longer appears to keep the list in import.c.

When searching for a more current list than I could find elsewhere, I encountered what appears to be an up-to-date list from Google as of May 2017.

https://github.com/google/pytype/blob/master/pytype/pyc/magic.py

Comment: the original data is [from CPython repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3460198f6ba40a839f105c381f07179aba1e8c61/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L131)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Igor Popov's answer.

To check the version of the compiled script from a newer version of Python:

```
# written in python3

filename = "outfit.cpython-39.pyc"

with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    magic = f.read(4)

print(int.from_bytes(magic[:2], 'little'))
```

You can lookup the output number here:
https://github.com/google/pytype/blob/master/pytype/pyc/magic.py