# Is .pyc platform independent?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I recently started python development on raspberry pi. While reading about .pyc file to speed up the start up, I was wondering if I test a .pyc file on PC, given that same python modules are available on Rpi, will it work directly ? Please also include what happens if python version or any of module version differs on target platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the Python version differs, or the source files have a newer timestamp, the .pyc files are discarded and regenerated the first time there's any attempt to load them. From that perspective, trying to mess with them seems rather silly -- you're saving very little time, even on an RPi, and even that only the first time those modules are loaded, as on subsequent loads you'd have locally generated copies.

Comment: don't bother about .pyc files. always use .py files, the compiled version is generated automatically.

Comment: The compiled version is not generated if the file is being run from a folder that's read only for the running user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compiled Python bytecode files are architecture-independent, but VM-dependent. A .pyc file will only work on a specific set of Python versions determined by the magic number [stored in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807541/is-there-a-way-to-know-by-which-python-version-the-pyc-file-was-compiled).

Comment: Can you explain VM dependent part a lil bit in detail ? Thanks

Comment: @dastaan, follow the link? It explains in great detail. (Perhaps "runtime version dependent" would be clearer).

Comment: @dastaan: Python is made up of a large shared library which contains the Python VM and a few select modules, the Python standard library which contains the majority of the modules, and a small stub executable that initializes the VM and feeds it a file and optionally the REPL.

Comment: @dastaan, the last four words of this post that we're commenting on -- "stored in the file" -- is a link, and has been since said post was first created.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: Yes. Just keep in mind that your code must be OS-aware too.

And use the same version of python in both platforms.