# How to identify the Python interpreter version for an undocumented .py module?

Tags: python, module, versioning, interpreter, cpython

Is there an implemented program solution to identify which version of the Python interpreter is supported for an undocumented .py module except for manually looking into the source code?

```
$ python get_py_version my_module.py
'2.6 version module'
```

Problem arose after installing an undocumented package in 3.x interpreter to discover during the import there are `print` statements from 2.x interpreter

Comment: Nope, looking at the code is pretty much it. Unless the developer put in documentation (docstrings, comments, or an explicit version check).

Comment: Simply run module test suite - if all tests pass, module is supported by your interpreter. If this is bare module without any tests - your guess is as good as mine. As far as I know there is no generic solution for this task. Of course you may try to use 2to3 and prepare your module manually, but problem still occurs - without test suite you cannot know if code 'works'. Any code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is a missing feature in Python, it would be easy to implement as a part of interpreter to infer the supported version from module syntax

Comment: @ŁukaszR. there is no test suite, what if I installed 3.x version in 2.x interpreter. I was hoping the already implemented program solution was available to infer the version from module source code

Comment: Ask the person who wrote the module.

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy I think it would be pretty hard to implement non-ambiguous algorithm. `print()` is trivial, but a lot of other stuff is not. Also, some modules may be 100% suitable to get "Python 2.0" or even maybe "1.x" as interpreter version.

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy: that's nigh impossible; that'd require an endless list of modules to track as well as syntax. Python has a long history of excellent forward compatibility as well, with the only major exception being the Python 2 to 3 transition.

Comment: @ŁukaszR. having a module to estimate the lowest supported version or something

Comment: @MartijnPieters then it might get started as the 2.x or the 3.x version check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is just a text file, there is no way for you to automagically find out what version of Python it was written in. And I don't know if there is much motivation to add this in to the language, especially considering how glaringly obvious it is when you have a py3 vs a py2 file (search for print, check future imports etc.).

However you can tell the difference if you are looking at a .pyc file. As these were compiled by a specific interpreter, there is normally a component of the file that gives the hex value for the interpreter used.

See here for more detail: [Is there a way to know by which Python version the .pyc file was compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807541/is-there-a-way-to-know-by-which-python-version-the-pyc-file-was-compiled)